# Backand: Sign user in immediately after registering?

Tags: backand

Having trouble doing this - is it even possible?

Sign-up Email Verification is off, and I'm doing this in the config:

```
BackandProvider.setAppName( 'test' );
BackandProvider.runSigninAfterSignup( true );
// ... tokens, etc.
```

Getting this back in the response after hitting the `/1/user/signup` endpoint:

```
data : {
    currentStatus : 1,
    listOfPossibleStatus : [...],
    message : "The user is ready to sign in",
    token : "...",
    username : "tester@test.com"
}
```

Do I need to make another API call? Can't find where and with which params.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must make another API call to get token after sign up. If you use the Backand SDK by default it makes the second call.

```
$scope.signup = function (form) {
return Backand.signup(form.firstName, form.lastName, 
               form.username, form.password, 
               form.password,
               {company: form.company})
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.getUserDetails();
    return response;
});
```

};

If you lool at the SDK code, this is what happens there:

```
self.signup = function (firstName, lastName, email, password, confirmPassword, parameters) {
    return http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: config.apiUrl + urls.signup,
        headers: {
            'SignUpToken': config.signUpToken
        },
        data: {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
            parameters: parameters
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.SIGNUP);

        if (config.runSigninAfterSignup
            && response.data.currentStatus === 1) {
            return self.signin(email, password);
        }

        return response;
    })
};
```